# Pattern Matching

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am goingto be starting work soon on a new project at work. Essentially there are many chemical compounds here each has its own prefix / identifier. For example a couple of chars followed by a few ints and that sort of thing, tho they all vary.

I was wondering if there was an algorithm for matching these elements efficiently, opposed to having a massive if else.

I guess a hash map with key -> value with the key being some mask may be good but i was hoping someone could suggest something a little more sophisticated that i could use.

Because its not just for chemical compounds the number of different values it could be is huge.

Thanks

Comment: no, internal representations of compounds developed, but a database wont cut it as the word searched by the user can be absolutley anything, and i have to, based on that display appropriate information on it - which can come from many different databases - this why identifying the string correctly and more importantly "efficiently" is important

Comment: Where do these identifiers come from? Notice that for chemical compounds there are already well-established methods of storing identifiers and fingerprints and querying huge data sets efficiently. Don’t reinvent the wheel, don’t use your own, arbitrary identifier schema. Use some established method that benefits from decades of research and optimization.

Comment: i work for a pharmacutical firm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider these facts:

1) Two molecules can have same structural identifier, caused for example by stereometry or, comparing two complex molecules (especially with many benzen rings)

2) Consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier. It's defining unambiguous version of molecule structure, and you can extract structural formula from it. For example:

```
1/C2H6O/c1-2-3/h3H,2H2,1H3
```

is representing

```
CH3CH2OH (ethanol)
```

3) You can check MQL Molecular query language

4) Implementing it on your own may take a lot of time. There are some context-free grammars but they are very complex, try to find some free Molecule Query

Answer (score 0):

Convert your formula into a String and then use a regular expression matching, it will make your life easier and you will learn regular expressions, which is a something quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it professionally, create a grammar file and generate a parser using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).